# Moderator Election Time?

Tags: discussion, election

When are the moderator elections?

StackOverflow for example, does not show one for 2013 yet, isn't it time?

Comment: Moderator elections are held when more moderators are needed...that need not be annually.

Comment: Turns out, a new election process was just started. See http://stackoverflow.com/election.

Comment: And http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168992/february-2013-community-moderator-election